# Not related divs pushes each other. CSS3, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a strange behavior on my webpage layout.
When i add some more divs inside "sideBar" div, the central part of the webpage is pushed down. They are not related to the central part. They have borders and i see that they are far from 'main' div. Is there any way to prevent it or i should play with margins every time when i add a new div.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="sideBarLeft">
    <div id='article1'><h3>Article 1</h3><div> //Just added
    <div id='article2'><h3>Article 2</h3><div> //Just added
    <div id='article3'><h3>Article 3</h3><div> //Just added
    <div id='article4'><h3>Article 4</h3><div> //Just added
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#sideBarLeft {
  position: fixed;
  height: 800px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

#article1 {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here is the central part:

```
#container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 256px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px dotted #808080;
}
```

Here is the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you update the HTML as well please, and add the container, the wrapper, and the main div?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because you have something in the main div using clear:both;
Try changing it to clear:right; or remove it

Comment: the html would help too

Comment: I think having a float and a position fixed is conflicting btw

Comment: how big is the screen you are using? Do you have enough room for a 250px box then 256px margin and then 600px container? When out of space it gets forced down.

Comment: What width are you getting with the H3